# JFrame Frame Icon Not Displayed Unless Program Run From Terminal

Tags: java, swing

I finally finished my first real program and have been trying to put some finishing touches on it. One of these finishing touches was packaging it up with icons and everything. The problem is, the icon only shows when I run the jar from the terminal. For example, when I double click the jar to run it I only see the Duke mascot. I am activating the same jar file, but in different ways and getting different results.

Example 1 (Terminal).
[image: From Terminal]
Notice how the icon does show up in my tray.

Example 2 (Double Click).
[image: Double click]
Notice how the icon does not show up in my tray.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what the problem even is?

Thanks so much.

Edit 1: Code

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("notebook_builder_icon.gif");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

Comment: Sorry it would have just been odd to crop to keep all my tray, title bar, program, terminal, and directory in the same image.

Comment: I'm actually doing it by creating a URL object like "URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("notebook_builder_icon.gif");". I then pass that to the ImageIcon class. Finally, I call frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage).

Comment: Can you show the code you're using.

Comment: Without looking at the code you using for loading images, it's hard to tell. Though please have a look at how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), might be this be of some help on the topic :-)

Comment: I added the code in an edit, but I'll check out that link!

Comment: but both of your screen shot does not have any image icon.

Comment: Arijit, look in the tray going down the left of my screen. Notice one has a hammer and paper while another has the duke mascot.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the `terminal` and `double click`is the context of the execution location. When running from the `terminal`, the execution context will be the directory you executed the java command from. When double clicking the Jar the context will be system dependent. You can use `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());` to output the path.

And in your `terminal`, your context was `~/Programming/java`, while `doublle click` makes the context current folder of the `.jar` file.

Comment: So to fix this, should I find a way to set the context to be the same as it was in terminal?

Comment: have you tested the 2 paths?

Comment: I think I found a solution! What if I pass getResource() new File("logo.gif").getAbsolutePath() instead of just the string?

Comment: Dude, is there a difference between the 2 windows? They both don't have a icon I think. And I was wrong about `java -jar` and `double click` for running the `jar`, because apparently they both have the same context in your case I think.

Comment: @ROROROOROROR The icons are different in the application dock to the left of the screenshots.

Comment: @user1472065 can you post the contexts by `double click` and `java -jar`?